# Parsing user agent OS Version is empty?

Tags: linux, parsing, operating-system, debian, user-agent

For the below user agent, the os version seems to be empty, why does it has no value ? Won't there be any value for it ?

```
User Agent = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.22+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Chromium/17.0.963.56 Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.22+ Debian/7.0 (3.4.2-2.1) Epiphany/3.4.2
```

Result:

```
ua_family = Epiphany, os_family = Debian, os_version = , device_family = Other, device = Desktop
```

Parsing user agent from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents/).

Comment: What would you do with this information if you had it?

Comment: I am trying to identify the device with that information.

Answer (score 1):

The [main source file](https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents/blob/master/user_agents/parsers.py) of the library is super simple to read -- it doesn't look like it knows a ton about Linux distributions (unless they also happen to be some kind of mobile OS):

```
MOBILE_DEVICE_FAMILIES = (
    ...
)

PC_OS_FAMILIES = (                   <-- no Linux! :(
    'Windows 95',
    'Windows 98',
    'Windows ME',
    'Solaris',
)

MOBILE_OS_FAMILIES = (
    ...
)

MOBILE_BROWSER_FAMILIES = (
    ...
)

TABLET_DEVICE_FAMILIES = (
    ...
)

TOUCH_CAPABLE_OS_FAMILIES = (
    ...
)

TOUCH_CAPABLE_DEVICE_FAMILIES = (
    ...
)
```

If all you care about is grabbing the OS information from your UA line, there are several sections of the UA line separated by '/':

```
Mozilla                                  <-- Note: no "User Agent = "
5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit
535.22+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Chromium
17.0.963.56 Chrome
17.0.963.56 Safari
535.22+ Debian
7.0 (3.4.2-2.1) Epiphany
3.4.2
```

You basically want to recognize the `(X11; Linux x86_64)`, `Debian`, `7.0 (3.4.2-2.1) Epiphany`, and `3.4.2` parts, which tell you "This is a Debian 7.0-based Linux distro on x86_64 with kernel version 3.4.2-2.1."

You could always create a pull request and add some Linux versions to this!